# Error polling getblocktemplate {"code":-4,"message":"Failed to parse wallet address"}

Tags: monero, cryptonote

I am trying to setup a cryptonote pool on my VPS. I am running the coin daemon and configured the wallet rpc.

The config is the same as here 
https://github.com/fancoder/cryptonote-universal-pool except the daemon which runs on port 26968. This is my netstat output :

```
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                 1086/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       25062/redis-server 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28390/electroneum-w
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1017/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:26967           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       26867/electroneumd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26968         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26867/electroneumd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1176/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      5641/redis-server *
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1176/apache2     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1017/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           782/dhclient
```

Nevertheless I get error

> Error polling getblocktemplate {"code":-4,"message":"Failed to parse wallet address"}

when i run

```
node init.js
```

Any Ideas how to fix this ? I couldn't find anything useful in the net.

Comment: This was a simple fix. The wallet address was cut at the end.

Comment: please post how you fixed it as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was that the address was cut in the config.json file due nano not displaying all the line.

So if you run into this problem check if the address is correct :)